# Receiving tab error "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" even after converting from spaces to tabs in visual studio code

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I keep receiving this error from my application:

**File "", line 67**

```
for o in obj["physical_address"]:
                                ^
```

**TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation**

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/location')
def get_testing_location():
    """Return selected state from drop down menu"""

    state = request.args['testing-state']
    url = f'https://covid-19-testing.github.io/locations/{state.lower()}/complete.json'
    res = requests.get(url)
    data = res.json()
    for obj in data:
        if obj["physical_address"]:
            for o in obj["physical_address"]:
                add=o["address_1"] 
                state=o["city"]
                print(f'{add} {state}')

    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
```

I have converted my visual studio code editor to use tabs instead of spaces and yet I still receive the same error.

Comment: does the editor convert spaces to tabs or just from now on it will be tabs not spaces? even if it converts, perhaps it doesn't convert e.g. 2 spaces into one tab (if it's 4 spaces). In which case you could try to convert all tabs to spaces in the document and see if you still get the error

Comment: I see spaces on the `if obj["physical_address"]:` line.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: You need to use the "Edit" view. The rendered output converts tabs to spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `"editor.renderWhitespace": "all"` in Settings.json. There may be spaces and tabs mixed in your code. It's recommended to indent all by spaces.
2. Convert indentation to 4 spaces:

[image]

Save the file to see if the error goes away.